# How to add custom matcher inline for one time to expect

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I want to test that the value returned equals 3. I can add custom matcher like this:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
        toBeThree: function () {
            return {
                compare: function (value) {
                    return {
                        message: 'Expected ' + value + ' to be 3',
                        pass: value === 3
                    };
                }
            };
        }
    });
});
```

And use it like this:

```
expect(fn()).toBeThree();
```

But what if I want to get this validation just one time. Is there something like this?

```
expect(fn()).toMatch(function(returndValue) {
   return returndValue === 3;
});
```